# "foo->bar()" versus "(*foo).bar()"

Tags: c++, pointers

What is difference in expressions `foo->bar()` and `(*foo).bar()`?

Those choices has equal results. So the code:

```
string *str = new string("Hello");

cout<<str->c_str()<<endl;
cout<<(*str).c_str()<<endl;
```

prints:

```
Hello
Hello
```

Maybe `foo->bar()` and `(*foo).bar()` difference in assembly code and memory usage?

Comment: The difference is two extra key strokes, and I'm not being snarky. For raw pointers that is literally the difference. class-level operator overloads can cowboy up different behavior, but that's not what you're showing.

Comment: I count three extra keystrokes. `-`+`SHIFT`+`>`, that's three, versus `SHIFT`+`(`+`*` then `SHIFT`+`)`+`.`, that's six.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn’t mean you should. The correct way to access members through pointers in C++ is `->`. Full stop.